# Execute a function after specific function is called (repeat this)

Tags: javascript, promise, dom-events

```
game.start(param1, param2, (e) => {

     axios.post(e).then(() => {
         console.log("axios callback got executed"):
     })


}, (b) => {
   console.log("execute this after axios callback gets executed")
}
```

`(e)` callback of `game.start` gets executed multiple times. Let's say 10 times.

`(b)` callback of `game.start` gets executed much less times. Let's say 3 times.

Now, whenever it's time to execute `(b)` callback, When code gets in there , I don't want my `console.log` to get executed if `axios call` is not finished yet. Then, the whole process repeats over and over again. What would be the optimal solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question right, but does it make sense to return in your (e) callback the Promise. And use (b) callback in "then()" statement of that Promise that returned in (e) function?

Comment: i need to have (e) and (b) callbacks. i can't change (b) callback to promise.then

Comment: (e) needs to return a promise if its async and you want to be able to run after it finishes

Comment: yeah.  something like that.

Comment: I really do not see a way to make it then in that state, because of Promises have been created for those reasons. You can not use axios in sync mode, but you can try to use XMLHttpRequest() in sync mode. Than the rest of the code will wait while it is finished.

Comment: Please post the code of  `game.start`  and how it uses those callbacks.